Issue with @ConfigurationProperties and @Value when used together in spring
I'm using @ConfigurationProperties and @Value both with record class (Java 21 & Spring Boot starter 3.2.2). But the properties with @Value is populating as null. I've came across few thread which explains the Nested properties scenario here - Spring Inject Values with @ConfigurationProperties and @Value
Can anyone help me understanding why is this not working for me?
application.yaml
abc:
  property1: value1
  property_name2: value2

Record
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
public record Model(
   String property1,
   @Value("${property_name2}") String property2) {
}

Output:
Model[property1=value1, property2=null]


Don't combine them, or rather you cannot combine them. @Value only works on spring managed beans, an @ConfigurationProperties isn't and is loaded very early in the process. If you make it an @Component it will fail again as it will now ignore the @ConfigurationProperties and fail to retrieve the value. Why is there a mismatch in the first place? Why not simply rename the property in the property file?

As @M.Deinum explained in the comments, you can't use @ConfigurationProperties with @Value.
I assume there is a good reason why you can't just rename the property in the property file (or the field in the Model record).
I have come up with a few options to solve your problem:
Option 1:
Adding a 'getter' to retrieve property2, which actually uses propertyName2
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
public record Model2(String property1, String propertyName2) {
    public String property2() {
        return propertyName2;
    }
}

Option 2: Change the Model record to be a Component and using @Value to inject the values from the property file.
@Component
public record Model(
        @Value("${abc.property1}")
        String property1,
        @Value("${abc.property_name2}")
        String property2) {
}

Option 3:
Change Model to a class and use constructor binding to map the properties to the attributes
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
public class Model3 {

    private final String property1;
    private final String property2;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public Model3(String property1, String propertyName2) {
        this.property1 = property1;
        this.property2 = propertyName2; // Map propertyName2 to property2
    }

    public String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }

    public String getProperty2() {
        return property2;
    }
}

You could also use @ConfigurationProperties on a @Bean method to create an instance of your Model record, but I think that will end up being too cumbersome, and really only for cases where you really cannot edit your Model class.
